# A lot of jade syntax errors after express 3 migration

Tags: express, pug

I have just updated my express version 2 to express 3 for my web application. I suddenly started to receive many weird syntax errors.

Initially I thought something changed with the layout structure because I got such errors:

```
SyntaxError: views/fragments/menu_items_admin.jade:1
  > 1| extends ../layout_tools
    2| 
    3| block menu_items
    4|     include ../fragments/menu_items_admin

Unexpected identifier
    at Function (<anonymous>)
    at assertExpression (node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:39:3)
    at Object.Lexer.attrs (node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:593:20)
```

But layouts still work.

Another error:

```
SyntaxError: views/fragments/admin/works.jade:12
    10|     script(src='/js/#{SOURCES["jquery.tags.js"]}')
    11|     script(src='/js/#{SOURCES["wh.js"]}')
  > 12|     if CONFIG.dev
    13|         script(src='/js/external/typeahead.js')
    14|     else
    15|         script(src='/js/external/typeahead.min.js')

Unexpected identifier
    at Function (<anonymous>)
    at assertExpression (node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:39:3)
    ...
```

What else can it be? Some layouts work, some don't. The errors shown are mainly at `include` expression.

Comment: It may help if you posted the syntax errors you get.

Comment: I was just migrating the question from the old one I posted (and deleted) (as I am debugging trying to search what causes the problems)

Answer (score 1):

These is this [migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)

I would like to add on the jade part, that the `'` and `"` MUST alternate in expressions like:

```
a(hreh="/dynamic/#{'link'}")
```

In the versions of jade that express 2 used, using only `'` or only `"` was fine.

Another change I see is that the scope of variable declared inside the jade templates changed a little:

Assume you give the following data context to the `render` function:

```
{
    categories: [ ... ]
}
```

and one jade file:

```
div
    for category in categories
        a(href='#') #{category.name}
div
    include child
```

and the `child` jade

```
categories = categories || []
for category in categories
    span #{category.name}
```

In the main jade file `categories` is now `undefined` what in the versions used by express 2 was the given array. This is throwing errors like:

```
  > 21|     for category in categories
    22|         a(href='#') #{category.name}

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jade.debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:152:8), <anonymous>:1052:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

On any `script` or `style` tags make sure you change them to `script.` and `style.`

According to the Jade updates you have to do that. I was having problems with Google Analytics code until I read that on the Git repo

Example:

```
script.
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'yourdomain.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```